# Batch Conversion Domain to IP

Tags: perl, url, ip

I have a list of domains I would like to convert to their respective IP. Let's say:

domain1.com
domain2.com
domain3.com

I would like to get the IP of each of these domains, such as:

domain1.com -> 111.111.111.111
domain2.com -> 222.222.222.222
domain3.com -> 333.333.333.333

I'm using a Perl script I found online and adding my domain list where it says :

```
echo "
<insert_list>
" | perl -MSocket -lne'
my $address = ( split /:/ )[ 0 ] or next;
my $number  = inet_aton $address;
my $ip      = inet_ntoa $number;
print "$address -> $ip";
'
```

This works, but some of the domains on my list have expired and no longer have IPs, in which case I get the following error message:

```
Bad arg length for Socket::inet_ntoa, length is 0, should be 4 at -e line 4, <> line 9.
```

I'd like to have a printed list that also tells me if a domain is unassigned. Example:

domain1.com -> 111.111.111.111
domain2.com -> 222.222.222.222
domain3.com -> 333.333.333.333
domain4.com -> Unknown Host

My list is fairly long: I have about 500 domains to organize and clean-up. What would be the best way to get the IP of each domain?

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Try changing the `$ip` assignment line to:

```
my $ip = $number ? inet_ntoa $number : "Unknown Host";
```

This checks the `$number` variable to see whether it's empty or not, and only if it isn't does it call `inet_ntoa` to convert the address to a printable form. If `$number` is empty, it assigns the string "Unknown Host".